# Sort bash find results before opening files

Tags: bash, macos

I'm on MacOSX 12.6, the following terminal command opens all the files I need, but it would be far more useful if the files opened in alphabetical order. For some reason everything is found, but opens in random order.

```
cd /Volumes/Disk2/Books; find ./ -type f -regex '.*[advert]_00[1-5]_2023\.pdf' -exec open {} \;
```

I can't see anything in the find documentation to affect sort order in the output. Previous answers to this type of question don't appear to work with ''-exec open' (I might be doing this wrong, sorry, inexperienced, I'm here to learn!)

Comment: `find`produces the files in directory order. I wouldn't do this is bash, but in Ruby or Perl or something similar. In this case you can load the list of pathes into an array and then sort it according to the basename of the pathes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
find whatever -exec open {} \;
```

do

```
find whatever | sort | xargs -n 1 open
```

That's assuming your file names don't contain newlines or quote characters.

Comment: Note: this will struggle with filenames containing whitespace or quoting characters. Unfortunately I don't believe MacOS supports `sort -z` like the GNU version does which is necessary to robustly run this in a single pipeline, so if that limitation matters to you then you'll probably have to split this apart into several steps or switch to something like python.

Comment: @tjm3772 no, it won't struggle with anything other than newlines as I mentioned. You'd only need `sort -z` if you used `find ... -print0` which would only be necessary if the file names contained newlines. For any other characters in the file names, what I posted will work fine. If I hadn't included `-n 1` in the call to `xargs` THEN there'd be a problem with other white space characters too. Quoting chars wouldn't be a problem either way.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm really grateful you took the time and this works very well for my purpose.

Comment: Unless MacOS `xargs` is significantly different from GNU, testing suggests otherwise. `touch 'foo "bar' ; find | sort | xargs -n1` prints `xargs: unmatched double quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option` when I test it, granted it's a ubuntu box and not macos.

Comment: @tjm3772 well, I stand corrected, I've never come across that limitation  with `xargs` before. Thanks for the info.

Comment: And to clarify my first comment, normally you'd fix the xargs quote thing with `find -print0 | xargs -0` but with a sort in the middle that only works if sort can also support null terminators. GNU sort does with `sort -z` and MacOS sort apparently does not, so people on MacOS would struggle to put that entire command in a single pipeline while fixing all possible complications.

Answer (score 0):

the output of the `find` is piped (`|`) to the `sort`, which sorts the file names alphabetically and the sorted file names are then passed to the `open` command using `xargs`, which opens them.

something like this

```
cd /Volumes/Disk2/Books; find ./ -type f -regex '.*[advert]_00[1-5]_2023\.pdf' | sort | xargs open
```

Comment: Thanks freeman this is great! I appreciate your answer coming in so quickly. Very helpful!